# Asp.net core and IE 11 rendering page issue

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

This is the weirdest error i have seen so far, and im not sure what i am doing wrong here.

I have asp.net core application. I wanted to wire-up different `layout` page to `Error` view instead of default `_layout.cshtml`. So here are the steps i followed:

1> Created a new asp.net core web application using VS 2015 community using default project template.

2> I added a new `_ErrorLayout.cshtml` layout page into `Views\Shared` Folder.
**_ErrorLayout.cshtml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>    
 <html>
   <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <title>My Application</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         @RenderBody()
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

3> Then i wired up `Error.cshtml` to new `_ErrorLayout.cshtml` layout.
**Error.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ErrorLayout.cshtml";   
}

<h1>Error.</h1>
<h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications</strong>, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>, and restarting the application.
</p>
```

4> Just for local testing purpose, in startup's configure method, i wire-up `/Home/Error` view for development environment.
**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
    }
```

5> For testing pupose throw exception in Home's Index method.
**Home.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        throw new Exception();            
    }
}
```

Now whenever application starts it goes to error page as expected.

**Issue**
`Error` view has unwanted text. I just want header and a message. So i deleted everything below `<h2>`.
**Modified Error.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ErrorLayout.cshtml";   
}

<h1>Error.</h1>
<h2>An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
```

Now if i run application i get `Http 500` error

[image]

I press F12 in IE 11 and check the response. It looks correct but i dont know why page does not render. Below is the captured response in IE11

[image]

**Notes**

- This is only happening in IE 11. Google chrome shows error page on application startup.
- If put the deleted text back in error view then IE 11 works.

Comment: You want to use VS2017, if you plan to developer in .Net Core.

Comment: @Win is that why i'm getting error? What VS 2015 has to do with this? if i run in vs 2105 & google chrome then it works

Comment: ASP.Net Core project structure was changed in VS2017 such as project.json file was removed. It is up to you.

Comment: Can you check when `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` is enabled?